# scale individual cell in a raster stack

Tags: r, scale, raster, r-raster

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
s <- stack(lapply(1:5, function(i) setValues(r, runif(100, -1, 1))))
```

I want to do two things:

1. replace negative values with NA in each raster layer
2. scale each cell using the mean and standard deviation for that cell across the 5 layers

   ```
   for(i in 1:5){

    s[[i]][s[[i]] < 0] <- NA
   }
   ```

For the second task, how can I scale individual cell using its mean and standard deviation
along the raster layer. For e.g. Is the following implementation correct?

```
scale(s, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
```

I think what it is doing is taking a layer, calculate the layer mean and sd and then
normalising each cell by using this mean and sd. What I want is to normalise
each cell using its mean and sd across the 5 layers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace negative values with NA you can use reclassify

Example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
s <- stack(lapply(1:5, function(i) setValues(r, runif(100, -1, 1))))
```

Solution

```
x <- reclassify(s, cbind(-Inf, 0, NA))
```

To apply `scale`, or a similar function, to each cell, you can use `calc`

```
z <- calc(x, scale)
```